# Add timestamp to image files in Joomla

Tags: php, css, image, joomla, timestamp

My Joomla site updates often. How do I add timestamp to all image files automatically? so that user will get the latest image. I want to also set how often the timestamp will be updated.

I see Gantry 5 has this function in one their plugin but it requires templates that uses gantry platform. I am using Joomlart's T3.

http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/faq/asset-timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way. Use a extension called Sourcerer. I was able to place `...jpg?{source}<?php echo date('Y,m') ?>{/source}` in my modules.